# python polars rolling highest

Tags: rolling-computation, python-polars

Is there a polars function I can use to get the the rolling highest like in the example below from df1 to df2?

```
df1=pl.DataFrame({"H":[3,2,1,4,6,5,9,8]})
df1
shape: (8, 1)
┌─────┐
│ H   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 3   │
│ 2   │
│ 1   │
│ 4   │
│ 6   │
│ 5   │
│ 9   │
│ 8   │
└─────┘
df2=pl.DataFrame({"H":[3,2,1,4,6,5,9,8],"rolling_highest":[3,3,3,4,6,6,9,9]})
df2
shape: (8, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────────┐
│ H   ┆ rolling_highest │
│ --- ┆ ---             │
│ i64 ┆ i64             │
╞═════╪═════════════════╡
│ 3   ┆ 3               │
│ 2   ┆ 3               │
│ 1   ┆ 3               │
│ 4   ┆ 4               │
│ 6   ┆ 6               │
│ 5   ┆ 6               │
│ 9   ┆ 9               │
│ 8   ┆ 9               │
└─────┴─────────────────┘
```

I tryed with groupby_dynamic or rolling_high but can get get only the highest value over a window . Would be easy extracting a list or an array and perform a cycle but would like to know if I can get the same result in polars. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `cummax`

```py
In [3]: df1.with_columns(rolling_highest=pl.col('H').cummax())
Out[3]:
shape: (8, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────────┐
│ H   ┆ rolling_highest │
│ --- ┆ ---             │
│ i64 ┆ i64             │
╞═════╪═════════════════╡
│ 3   ┆ 3               │
│ 2   ┆ 3               │
│ 1   ┆ 3               │
│ 4   ┆ 4               │
│ 6   ┆ 6               │
│ 5   ┆ 6               │
│ 9   ┆ 9               │
│ 8   ┆ 9               │
└─────┴─────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .... I was focused on rolling or groupby functions but cummax is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Please mark the answer as selected answer if it solved your problem.